# Cannot drag tab bar items onto a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

So in xcode I've dragged a tab bar controller onto the screen. I'm now trying to drag tab bar items onto the bottom part of that, but nothing is happening. (I'd show a screen shot, but I can't show the dragging thing).

How am I supposed to drag things onto the tab bar?

Ok, so it looks like the tab bar items are expanding to fill the whole tab bar and so they're being laid on top of each other - how do I stop that?

Answer (score 1):

You should drag to tab bar controller the whole view controllers. For example Table View Controller, or simple View Controller

Comment: Drag them to tab bar controller. And you may reorder the controllers by dragging and changing the order of tab bar icons

Comment: right, but they're not in the objects part of the interface builder?

Comment: also, when I drag them on, I don't see two tab bar items show up?

Comment: What do you mean by two tab bar items?  You may in a case of manually created controllers create tab bar in a code

Comment: ok so let's say I want two buttons in my tab bar because I have two different view controllers that need to show up, how do I do that?

Comment: UITabBarItem *firstItem = [UITabBarItem initWithTitle:@"First" image:firstImage tag:1];
UITabBarItem *secondItem = [UITabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Second" image:secondImage tag:2];

NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithItems:firstItem, secondItem, nil];

[myTabBar setItems:itemsArray animated:YES];

Comment: so I can't do that through a xib file?